# Knockout - How to recreate a JSON object from modified form

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a JSON object that I used to create a form. This JSON object is parsed by KnockoutJS. Now, when I modify the form, I want the JSON object to be updated according to the modifications made in the form.

I really don't know what is the best way to procede. I know that I could reconstruct the JSON Object each time something has changed but this seems like a bad idea and a tedious process.

Is there a simple way to map each JSON Object field to form items in KnockoutJS ?

Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm currently doing: http://goo.gl/IWiUj

**Update:**
I don't know what is the procedure but I created another question ,since there was already answers, with a better example of what I'm trying to achieve : [How to update a JSON Object that is represented in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221278/knockout-how-to-update-a-json-object-that-is-represented-in-a-form). Sorry.